# How to count the number of observations (in Excel)?

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets in an Excel file:

companies

```
  A       B      C     D     E
1 COMPANY SECTOR VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3
2 Sony    Tech         2.40  no
3 Ikea    Home   7     1.44  yes
4 ING     Bank   5        0  yes
5 BofA    Bank   0           no
6 Google  Tech            0  yes
7 Staples Home         5.24  no
8 Trump   Ego    5     9.99  yes
9 ABN     Bank         2.64  no
```

This sheet holds hundreds of `VAR`s for thousands of companies. There are many missing values (empty cell is missing value, `0` actually is an observed value). I need to know how many observations I have for each `VAR`. I need (1) an overall count of the number of observations and (2) the number of observations for companies that are in the banking sector. In the sheet below, (1) is in column `B`, (2) in column `C`:

variables

```
   A       B     C
1 VARIABLE TOTAL BANK
2 VAR_1    4     2  
3 VAR_2    7     2
4
5          Some random comment...
6
7 VAR_3    8     3
```

Let's take `VAR_1` as an example. Looking at the `companies` sheet, there are 4 observations for this variable (`7`, `5`, `0` and `5`). Looking solely at banks (`SECTOR == 'Bank')` there are 2 observed values (`5` for ING and `0` for BofA).

It is possible that in the `variables` sheet, there are comments in between different variables (although never in in column `A`; this column holds either a variable name or is empty). Also, the *order* of variables might not be the same. So in `companies` could say

```
  ... GH     GI     GJ
1     VAR_40 VAR_41 VAR_42
```

while in `variables` it says

```
    A
...
60  VAR_40
61  VAR_42
62  VAR_41
```

My question is: what formula's can calculate the number of observations in `variables` columns `B` and `C`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Formulas for this. You can use a Pivot

See this screenshot

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

Using Formulas

[image]

For the `Var2`, `Var3`, adjust the columns in the formula accordingly.

For example `B14` for `Var2` will become `=COUNTA(D2:D9)` and `C14` will become `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,$C$12,D2:D9,"<>")`

**FOLLOWUP (FROM COMMENTS/CHAT)**

Since your table is not continuous, I would recommend VBA (UDF) approach to this so that you can actually copy the formula down ;)

Paste these two codes in Module

```
    Function getVarCount(rngVar As Range, strSector As String, rngRw As Range) As Variant
        getVarCount = "Incomplete Data in Formula"

        If rngVar Is Nothing Or _
           rngRw Is Nothing Or _
           Len(Trim(strSector)) = 0 Then Exit Function

        Dim aCell As Range, SectorRange As Range
        Dim colSector As Long, colVar As Long

        Set aCell = rngRw.Find(What:=rngVar.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            colVar = aCell.Column
        Else
            getVarCount = "VAR Heading Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        Set aCell = rngRw.Find(What:="Sector", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            colSector = aCell.Column
        Else
            getVarCount = "SECTOR Heading Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        Set SectorRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngRw.Parent.Name).Columns(colSector)

        Set aCell = SectorRange.Find(What:=strSector, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If aCell Is Nothing Then
            getVarCount = strSector & " Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        getVarCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngRw.Parent.Name).Columns(colVar)) - 1
    End Function

Function getVarSectorCount(rngVar As Range, strSector As String, rngRw As Range) As Variant
        getVarSectorCount = "Incomplete Data in Formula"

        If rngVar Is Nothing Or _
           rngRw Is Nothing Or _
           Len(Trim(strSector)) = 0 Then Exit Function

        Dim aCell As Range, SectorRange As Range
        Dim colSector As Long, colVar As Long

        Set aCell = rngRw.Find(What:=rngVar.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            colVar = aCell.Column
        Else
            getVarSectorCount = "VAR Heading Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        Set aCell = rngRw.Find(What:="Sector", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            colSector = aCell.Column
        Else
            getVarSectorCount = "SECTOR Heading Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        Set SectorRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngRw.Parent.Name).Columns(colSector)

        Set aCell = SectorRange.Find(What:=strSector, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If aCell Is Nothing Then
            getVarSectorCount = strSector & " Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If

        '=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,$C$12,D2:D9,"<>")
        getVarSectorCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngRw.Parent.Name).Columns(colSector), _
                                                                   strSector, _
                                                                   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngRw.Parent.Name).Columns(colVar), _
                                                                   "<>")
End Function
```

You can call it from the Excel cell as we discussed in Chat

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: That's great, but the variables sheet is sort of my dashboard for the dataset. It would be great if I can just add a formula to get these results as an additional column to the worksheet. Would you happen to know how to do this also?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Updating the answer

Comment: I found `=HLOOKUP(A2;n!$A$1:$OC$2;2;FALSE)` myself, but this doesn't allow to filter on 'Banks'

Comment: Thanks it works great. However, I have hundreds of variables and they are (1) not always in the same order on the `companies` and `variables` sheet (2) on the `variables` sheet, sometimes interrupted by comments. So with these formula's, I would have to lookup the cellrange for each variable manually (and re-check every time variables are added, deleted or switched back and forth the sheet). That's why I was trying to read the variable name in `variables` (`A2` for `VAR_1` for example) and automagically lookup the corresponding column in `companies` (`C2:C9`). Could you add this functionality?

Comment: Of course, please see https://www.dropbox.com/s/su9j6lhe1let98e/Stackoverflow.xlsx :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28599/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-pr0no)